# Trying to kick user by the first mention

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an admin bot in discord, but can't make it kick members by the first mention. I was always getting errors, but now, suddenly, it's just doing nothing.

This is my code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("ab!kick")) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
            if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
                try {
                    message.mentions.members.first().kick;
                } catch {
                    message.reply("I do not have permission to kick " + message.mentions.members.first());
                }
            } else {
                message.reply("You do not have permission to kick " + message.mentions.members.first());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried `message.members.mentions.first()` and `message.mentions.users.first()` but no success.

Comment: kick is a method, not a property. `kick()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call the `kick` function by using parenthesis

```
// Old (do not use)
try {
  message.mentions.members.first().kick
} catch {
  // ...
}

// New
try {
  message.mentions.members.first().kick()
} catch {
  // ...
}
```